# Mod Rewrite: HTACCESS How to rewrite a single URL to another?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have read through a ton of other similar questions and have tried too many combinations of code, but nothing works. I just need to add a single rewrite (not redirect) to my htaccess:

Here is the deal... I have this current URL:

```
https://example.com/all-categories/202/showCategory/54-Floor-Plans
```

and I want it to display as:

```
https://example.com/floor-plans
```

I still need it to actually be going to the original URL in the background to pull data, but display it differently in the browser URL.

Here is one of the options I tried (didn't work):

```
RewriteRule ^floor-plans$ all-categories/202/showCategory/54-Floor-Plans [L]
```

It is probably something extremely simple... HELP PLEASE!

Comment: I just had a thought... This is all running on Joomla 3.6.5 and I already have the basic internal rewrites going for the entire site so my initial "https://example.com/all-categories/202/showCategory/54-Floor-Plans" has already re-written once. Could this be causing my newly added specific rewrite rule to not work at all? I'm just fishing for ideas at this point...

Comment: do you have 'RewriteEngine On'

Comment: it also depends where you are putting this directive in the file. Is the URL on the page `https://example.com/floor-plans`? And what do you mean by "doesn't work" exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is you're rewriting to a file that doesn't exist.

You'll need to find the non-rewritten URL.

For example:

`RewriteRule ^floor-plans$ index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=54`

To find this you could try turning off Search Engine Friendly (SEF) URL's, open the page and check the URL.

You can also read more about SEF URL's here if you wish.
https://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs

Comment: This led me to the correct solution... I did have to find and use the original, non-sef URL. The issue was me trying to use the already-rewritten URL to re-write a second time.